# PHP for loop displaying strange results

Tags: php, for-loop

I have this code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i+=0.1) {
    echo "$i<br>";
}
```

if the variable `$max = 6;` the results are: `1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 .... 5.8, 5.9, 6` , but when the variable `$max = 4` the results are: `1, 1.1 ... 3.8, 3.9`, but the number 4 is missing.

Please explain this behavior, and a possible solution to this.

the results are the same when i use the condition `$i <= $max;` or `$i < $max;`

The bug occurs when `$max` is `2, 3 or 4`

Comment: I think this has something to do with roundoff problems: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
In fact, the error is not the missing 4 but the printed 6

Comment: read the red block about Floating point precision. [Floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: if i modify the loop 'for($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i+=0.1)' the problem remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the precision when using integers,

like this:

```
$e = 0.0001;
   while($i > 0) {
   echo($i);
   $i--;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision.

So to overcome this you could multiply your numbers by 10.
So `$max` is 40 or 60.

```
for($i = 10; $i <= $max; $i+=1) {
    echo ($i/10).'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$err = .000001//allowable error
for($i = 1; $i <= $max+$err; $i+=0.1) {
    echo "$i<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  You can use of number_format()

<?php
$max=6;
for($i = 1; number_format($i,2) < number_format($max,2); $i+=0.1) {
echo $i."<br>";     
}
```

?>

Comment: set `$max` = 100 and see what happens. The rounding error starts at 54.2 in my case.